# ASP.NET Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, html, string, smtp, format

I have made a control that creates an electronic invite to an event.  The user inputs their information into textboxes and the system gathers that information, adds it to the HTML for the email and then sends it.

I am encountering an error when I combine all the parts.  My code is below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(YourEmailBox.Text, YourNameBox.Text);

    message.From = fromAddress;

    message.To.Add(FriendEmailBox.Text);
    message.Subject = EmailSubject;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = "<html>" + string.Format(EmailBody, YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text) + "</html>";
    smtpClient.Send(message);

    YourNameBox.Text = YourEmailBox.Text = FriendNameBox.Text = FriendEmailBox.Text = PersonalNoteBox.Text = string.Empty;
    Label1.Text = "Email Successfully sent!";

}
```

It is giving me the input string was not in a correct format error on this line:

`message.Body = "<html>" + string.Format(EmailBody, YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text) + "</body></html>";`

Will you please help me out?

Comment: What is the value of EmailBody?  That is your culprit

Comment: EmailBody is an HTML formatted email with all the CSS and markup.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do with your String.Format statement?  What do you think the String.Format function does, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do:

message.Body = `string.Format("<html>{0}</html>",EmailBody.Text)`

I don't get why you have 3 arguments passed to string.Format, for example,
`"<html>" + string.Format("3","4","5") + "</html>"` will produce

`<html>3</html>`

Comment: +1.  You're the only one who caught that.  I mis-read the question 4 times before I realized he was using String.Format incorrectly.  The error is undoubtedly caused by the runtime trying to turn his first argument into a valid composite format string.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9t40k6d.aspx

Comment: The other arguments are optional so I wanted to format them all in one statement in case they are used.

Comment: @CKallemeres - Even if they are optional, you are still doing string.Format incorrectly.  You should handle it once you know they will be used, not in case.  And even if you decide to use the other arguments, you will still have to change string.Format because it is incorrect.  The correct format can be found in the link that David provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Should it maybe be this instead?

```
message.Body = "<html>" + string.Format(EmailBody.Text, YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text) + "</html>";
```

(adding the .Text to EmailBody, assuming EmailBody is some kind of text based control)

Comment: EmailBody is an HTML formatted email with all the CSS and markup

Comment: So it's a string variable and not a control name?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking I would try `message.Body = "<html>" + string.Format(EmailBody.HtmlEncode(), YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text) + "</html>";`  Do you think this will work?

Comment: This has the same error the asker had (and I completely missed in my andwer).  See @Xaisoft's answer.  He's using `String.Format()` incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, right.  Totally missed that as well.  Guess it's time for the holiday to start.

Answer (score 1):

As XaiSoft pointed out you're using `string.Format()` incorrectly, replace:

```
message.Body =  "<html>" + string.Format(EmailBody, YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text) + "</html>";
```

With:

```
message.Body = string.Format(@"<html>{0}<br /><br />{1}<br /><br />{2}</html>",
                             EmailBody, YourNameBox.Text, PersonalNoteBox.Text)
```

If `YourNameBox.Text` and `PersonalNoteBox.Text` are optional, you'll just end up with 4 extra line breaks at the end of your email. If that is somehow a problem, you can always do this too:

```
var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(YourNameBox.Text) 
              ? string.Empty 
              : string.Format(@"<br /><br />{0}", YourNameBox.Text);

var personalNote = string.IsNullOrEmpty(YourNameBox.Text) 
                      ? string.Empty 
                      : string.Format(@"<br /><br />{0}", PersonalNoteBox.Text);

message.Body = string.Format(@"<html>{0}{1}{2}</html>", EmailBody, name, personalNote);
```

**EDIT**

Also, note the `@` symbol used in the format strings. This will treat your string as a literal, ignoring any escape characters that could also be causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, String.Replace is the only thing that worked for me when it comes to replacing values insiode html string.

"
{0}".Replace("{0}",YourValue)

Comment: Thanks, the Replace() worked fine when using html templates.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `EmailBody` variable does not contain the correct number of format items for `string.Format` to work.